# Does Background position on images stop animation?

Tags: html, css, keyframe

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/gna7r4L8/)

```css
.move
{
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move
{
    from{background-position: 0, 0}
    to{background-position:200%,200%}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move
{
    from{background-position: 0, 0}
    to{background-position:200%,200%}
}
```

```html
<div class="move"> </div>
```

Just remove `background-size` in the fiddle and see it. Why does it affect animation?

**EDIT**
If i change `to` in animation `to some pixels, say 200px` it works.

I tried to add a conde-snippet with the help of SO's CodeSnippet. I couldn't. Will anyone please do that?

Comment: I don't see looping animations with 100% background-position.

Answer (score 1):

A background-size of 100% can not be moved with percentage position properties (it is not intuitive, I know...)

Background-position in percentage sets the point where the percentage of the background and the percentage of the container dimensions match..

If the size is 100%, any point that you choose gives the final position

But it is not related to the animation , it is related to positioning per se

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `background-size`: try to set it to `100px, 100px` and you'll see the animation.

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/gna7r4L8/1/).

Comment: I have identified it. And i have edited the posts too. Why is it not working with %? Please let me know

Comment: @GopsAB - I don't know. Here is a fiddle with % both on background-size and on movement: https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/gna7r4L8/9/ - the issue is not the %, but the 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your percent value to [viewport percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) `vh` & `vw`.

```css
.move
{
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100vw 100vh;
     animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move
{
    from{background-position: 0 0}
    to{background-position: 200vw 200vh}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move
{
    from{background-position: 0 0}
    to{background-position:200vw 200vh}
}
```

```html
<div class="move"> </div>
```